# How do I fix these exceptions for creating a "browse" button function with tkinter in Python?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I know there are a lot of answers about how to implement a browse button, and I used those to create the following code, but Pycharm is still throwing exceptions that I don't understand, and the tkinter code is not well documented.

Here is the code that is throwing the exceptions:

```
import os
import fnmatch
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
master.geometry("550x125+10+10")

filePath = StringVar(None)
def browseFiles():
    file = askopenfilename(filetypes = (("text files","*.txt"),("all 
    files","*.*")), title = "Choose a File.")

    filePath.set(file)
    for f in file:
        E2.insert(1.0, filePath)
        return

L1 = Label(master, text = "Client Code:")
L1.place(x=10, y=10)
E1 = Entry(master, width = 20)
E1.place(x=80, y=10)
L2 = Label(master, text = "File Name:")
L2.place(x=10, y=40)
E2 = Entry(master, width = 50, textvariable=filePath)
E2.place(x=80, y=40)
B1 = Button(master, text="Browse", width=10, command=browseFiles)
B1.place(x=425, y=37)


master.mainloop()
```

The exceptions are as follows:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\klighthouse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
  32\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
      return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/klighthouse/PycharmProjects/untitled/Run_EPC.py", line 58, 
  in browseFiles
      E2.insert(1.0, filePath)
  File "C:\Users\klighthouse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
  32\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2686, in insert
      self.tk.call(self._w, 'insert', index, string)
  _tkinter.TclError: bad entry index "1.0"
```

The code will run, and the program works, but I think the exceptions are slowing it down, so I would love to get rid of them somehow. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you try using an integer (1) instead of 1.0 ? Might throw the exception away

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what is wrong. You can't use a floating point number as an index for an entry widget.

Comment: Changing it to just one does make the exceptions go away, but it adds "PY_VAR0" to the entry box in addition to the file path. How do I get rid of that?

Answer (score 1):

`E2.insert(1.0, filePath)` passes a double `1.0`, but it should be an integer. So `E2.insert(1, filePath)` fixes your issue.

Note: to insert in the beginning you should use `0` instead of `1` (unless it's empty)

`askopenfilename` only allows to open a single file, therefore a loop is not needed and you can simply write

```
def browseFiles():
    file = askopenfilename(filetypes = (("text files","*.txt"),("all files","*.*")), title = "Choose a File.")
    E2.insert(0, file)
    return
```

Comment: If it's empty, should I use 1 still?

Comment: @Kassandstorm if you want to put in the beginning then I would use 0, just for clarity.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is adding "PY_VAR0" to the beginning of the file path now, though. Do you know what I should do about that?

Comment: @Kassandstorm with `askopenfilename` you can only select 1 file, so you don't need the loop and can write `E2.insert(0, file)`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I deleted the loop, but it's still adding that "PY_VAR0"

Comment: @Kassandstorm dit you change `filePath` to `file`?

Comment: Ah, I did now. I was worried about that because of the "text variable" in the E2 code, but I didn't need that either. That works! Thank you! I'd been working on this for a while, so I really appreciate your time.